# Set the Current Datetime for Saxon in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I've got a very large number of XSLT transforms that I'm migrating to a new system. To facilitate regression testing, I've ran multiple example inputs through those transforms, and kept the input/output pairs to be used in JUnit tests.

This worked great for a few days, until suddenly, some of these tests failed. The source of the failure was tracked down to a date conversion - sometimes dates are given as month-day pairs, and the year is assumed based on the relation of that date to today's date. So, if the given date was `Oct. 1`, the transforms were suddenly returning `Oct. 1, 2014`, when `2013` was originally expected.

While I was reading the Saxon documentation, I stumbled across this: http://saxonica.com/documentation9.4-demo/html/using-xsl/commandline.html

> -now:yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss+hh:mm
>
> Sets the value of current-dateTime() (and implicit-timezone()) for the transformation. This is designed for testing, to enable repeatable results to be obtained for comparison with reference results, or to test that stylesheets can handle significant dates and times such as end-of-year processing.

This is **exactly** what I need, but unfortunately, I'm running these transforms (and their accompanying unit tests) in java, not from the command line. I looked around for some sort of transformer method, perhaps a property I could set, but have seen nothing so far. I *could* rewrite all the transforms to accept a current date parameter and set that programmatically, but would rather not solely for the purpose of testing.

**tl;dr** Are there any options out there for forcing a certain date to be returned from `current-datetime()` in Saxon in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The corresponding option in the Saxon API is Controller.setCurrentDateTime(). The Controller is Saxon's implementation of the JAXP Transformer, so you can down-cast the Transformer, or in s9api you can get to it from the XsltTransformer object.

Comment: I'm using an XsltTransformer, so `transformer.getUnderlyingController().setCurrentDateTime()` works great!